# find string if text not contain specific word

Tags: regex

I need to use regular expression to find match if specific word is not exist

Example 
   find fox if tiger not exist in text

**So the regex should match fox in**

```
"fox is an animal"
```

**and not match in**

```
"both fox and tiger are animals"
```

need one regular expession

Comment: Are you sure you need a single regex to do this? Why not have two regexes and accept the string if the first one matches and the other one does not?

Comment: Firstly -- what language? Secondly -- why do you need to do this in a single regex? Surely it makes more sense to write something along the lines of `if(! string.contains('tiger')) { match = string.find('fox') }`?

Comment: do you have to use a Regex this seems like it would be easier to use the `contains` method (or equivalent in whatever language) i.e. in java: `if(!string.contains("tiger")) { //Do something}`.

Answer (score 2):

In `linux` you can do this:

```
cat input.txt | grep -w fox | grep -vw tiger
```

Comment: It does not depend on Linux, but on grep, which is available for many platforms, even windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative look ahead and negative look behind to detect presence of unwanted words.

e.g.: `(?<!(tiger.*))(fox)(?!(.*tiger))`

**Note:** This approach is not supported by all languages.
          See compatibility list [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html).

Comment: You can drop one `.*` in each of the lookaround assertions. And this will only work with the .NET and JGSoft regex engines.